# Adding form values to a table with backbone and handlebars

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

The scenario is to add the values entered in form fields into a table on click of Add button. I am new to this both and not sure how data binding works.

My initial html is

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control" id="modelname"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" id="brandname"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" id="yearname"></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button></td>
    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody class="product-list">

    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="product-template">
     {{#each []}}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ model }}</td>
          <td>{{ brand }}</td>
          <td>{{ year }}</td>
            <td><div class="btn btn-primary">Edit</div>&nbsp;<div class="btn btn-danger">Delete</div></td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}

   </script>
```

I messed up in js for purpose of using handlebars as

```
var Product=Backbone.Model.extend({
     model:'',
     brand:'',
     year:''
});

var ProductCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Product
});

   var modelname= document.getElementById('modelname').value;
   var brandname=document.getElementById('brandname').value;
    var yearname= document.getElementById('yearname').value;
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '.product-list',
        tagName: 'tr',
        events:{
        "click .add": "create"
         },
        initialize:function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render:function()
        {
            var source=$('#product-template').html();
            var template=Handlebars.compile(source);
            var html=template(this.products.toJSON());
        },
       create: function(e){
        var product=new Product({
          model:modelname,
           brand:brandname,
          year:yearname
      })
          console.log(product.toJSON);
           products.add(product);
        modelname="";
        yearname="";
        brandname="";
         }

      });
  var products=new ProductCollection();
```

Share me an idea how to proceed. I don't get an error and at the same time, nothing happens! I am very new to backbone. Please tolerate blunders.

Comment: Look here http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/ Please post [Minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just try to follow the code in above link. Or you can use [Marionette framework](http://marionettejs.com/)

Comment: backbone use underscore template  which is good for small template. but handlebars provide much better than underscore for larger template

Comment: I am particularly asked to use handlebars Mahi.

Comment: I indeed checked them at first Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make and example how can achieve that with **underscore template** and **handlebars**. Use it for iterating over a collection of models to display a list of products.

### Underscore.js

```
<tbody class="product-list">
    <script type="text/template" id="product-template">
        <% _.each(products.models, function(product){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= product.get('modelName') %></td>
            <td><%= product.get('brand') %></td>
            <td><%= product.get('year') %></td>
        </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </script>
</tbody>
```

In script file define model:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Next, define a collection and add those model to the collection:

```
var ProductList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product
});
```

Most of the time we use view in Backbone application to do the rendering:

```
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.product-list',
    template: _.template($('#product-template').html()),
    render: function(products){
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            products: products
        }));    
    }
});
```

You can see from working code full app, and see that we call `render` method from `productView` and pass it  collection as argument: `this.productView.render(this.collection)`
Now we can use it as a list in template to iterate and display *modelName*, *brand* and *year* for each product in lists.

Working code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgasp99v/2/)

---

> I am particularly asked to use handlebars

### Handlebars.js

You have many errors in your code:

- define **instance of view** `var products = new ProductView();`, instead of that you define instance of ProductCollection();
- `var html=template(this.products.toJSON()); Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined` , check `initialize` method in working example, you need to define collection and listen to him, because every time we add something to collection we want to render `ProductView`
- `el: '.table'` not `el: '.product-list'`,
- `var modelname= document.getElementById('modelname').value;` `var brandname` ... - you make them as a global variables, instead of that place that variables inside `create()` method
- replace `var html=template(this.products.toJSON());` with `$('.product-list').html(template(this.products.toJSON()))`

First of all read documentation if something isn't clear: [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and check working example: [jsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/x8sqprsh/1/)

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks a lot for coming up with such a good help I needed. Could you even more elaborate the flow of data ? I am just started with backbone and still don't get it how.

Comment: i updated my answer, you have many errors, but I make working example with handlebars to make it easy to follow, so please check it!

Comment: Thanks so much.Appreciate it. By the way, How do I get json of a particular row in table as this.model ? Because, this.collection is the entire array and on click of say second row, second row element need to be populated in text field.

Comment: if you still have questions, then you should post new question, it will be much cleaner to follow you. Please keep in mind to accept my answer if is good enough for your main question. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761916/to-get-value-of-one-particular-row-in-a-table

Thanks to you too